# Eclipse plugin for psql/PostgreSQL code?

Tags: eclipse, plpgsql, postgresql

Do you have recommendations for a good PostgreSQL editor plugin for Eclipse?

The PostgreSQL code I have isn't very complex. However I'd like to edit it with syntax-coloring, decent auto-identation, code completion, etc., and it would be sweet to be able to send blocks or entire files to a jdbc connection and get the results. Up until now, I have edited my .sql files with Emacs, and try things by copying/pasting segments into a psql terminal I have next to Emacs.  Some of my code uses the psql primitives such as `\set var value` etc.  For example:

```
\set t mytable
drop table if exists :t;
create table :t (...);
```

However I would be happy to eliminate this and refactor the code to be proper PL/pgSQL functions. Or perhaps better, implement the dependency and procedural logic in Java and issue the sql queries via JDBC.  I still need to edit the sql files and try bits and pieces of them during development.

I tried the "official" Data Tools Platform (http://eclipse.org/datatools/) and configured it to use my localhost:5432 (which in fact is a port-forward via SSH to the actual PostgreSQL server that I'm using).  However, connecting to the DB hangs for several minutes (Eclipse doesn't even refresh the screen).  In general it feels quite heavy/slow
and I'm always afraid of if hanging without ability to interrupt it (it happened a few times and the only solution is to kill Eclipse; as you probably know, killing Eclipse isn't good as it's very hard/impossible to recover unsaved files).

The other plugin I tried is Toby's PL/SQL editor (https://sourceforge.net/projects/plsqleditor/), which seems very nice and promising, except the last signs of life on the sourceforge forums appear to be around 2007. Also I couldn't configure it to use the postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar that I have, and so I am unable to connect to my DB.

Any suggestions gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A free Eclipse plugin for Oracle and PostgreSQL can be found at http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/default.aspx
The plugin is in development.

Comment: this is a nice plugin. I've been using it for a few days now and there are a few rough edges in some areas, but overall it is fitting the bill nicely. There is also some pretty good integration with Eclipse. I like it & am looking foreward to seeing adoption and improvements. On thing I found a bit confusing is around setting up the connections, where there seems to be separate ways, 1. to get a schema browser and 2. to link a piece of sql source to allow for block execution.  Anyway thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Website is change to following http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/default.aspx

Comment: No longer free as of August 31, 2017.